# Several complex variables exercises with solutions

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, several-complex-variables

I am studying about several complex variables, and have found some great books regarding the topic, such as Several Complex Variables by Jaap Korevaar, Jan Wiegerinck, which also has exercises.
Can annyone recommend me a similar book that also has solutions to the exercises, so I can advance faster through the material?